# Launching fragment from fragment results in defualt screen shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As the title states I am trying to launch a fragment from another fragment via a button. This shouldn't be too hard of a task but, here I am struggling. When I click the button to launch the fragment it simply gives me a default fragment screen and not the one I made.

Not 100% sure what to do currently I

1. Made sure .OnFragmentInteractionListener was  implemented in my main activity for the fragment
2. Tried to load a known good fragment and it failed. Leading me to believe I am not launching the fragment correctly.
3. No errors come up

Update: Trying to implement interface to communicate with fragment from activity. Implemented interface on activity but, I need fragOut() method called when OnClick is triggered from fragment. Not sure what to do haven't worked with interfaces before.

Update2: Made interface and trying to get it to launch my method that launches another fragment. However, I am getting this error when trying to call the method

Update3: Made interface here [Using an interface to communicate from fragment to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676243/using-an-interface-to-communicate-from-fragment-to-activity/56676437#56676437) and shoved everything needed to create fragment inside interface method call in activity.

```
FATAL 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
  'void   rangers.socman.BattleRhythmFrag$doubleFrag.fragOut()' on a null
   object reference
    at rangers.socman.BattleRhythmFrag.onClick(BattleRhythmFrag.java:149)
```

OnClick() from fragment hosting buttons

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    switch(v.getId()){



        case R.id.newBattle:
        {
          doubleFrag testFrag;     
          testFrag.fragOut();
           }

        case R.id.editBattle:
        {
            EditBattleFrag editBattleF = new EditBattleFrag();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_content,editBattleF,editBattleF.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }

        case R.id.deleteBattle:
        {
            DeleteBattleFrag deleteBattleF = new DeleteBattleFrag();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_content,deleteBattleF,deleteBattleF.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }

        break;
        default:
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Interface created on Fragment hosting buttons

```
   public interface doubleFrag {
         void fragOut(Context context);
   }
```

Interface implemented on main activity

```
    @Override
public void fragOut() {

    NewBattleFrag test = new NewBattleFrag();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.home_content,test);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this could mean a lot of work but you could change you implementation. From what I can see you are trying to change the fragment from within the fragment. If you ask me it is the job of the Host Activity to change the fragments (if you are not using mvp or mvvm).

This can be achieved easily using an interface. Create a interface inside your fragment like this:

```
public interface myInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

When you instantiate you fragment in your activity (your activity should implement your interface), pass "this" as reference so the fargment knows the interface should communicate with the Activity when is requested to do so. This way you can actually let the Host Activity to handle its own process to change fragments

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

The blank screen you are getting could be from an error while changing fragments from within the fragments, maybe there is some info in the LogCat when you request the fragment transition that could help to understand the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you mean by passing "this". Tried a couple things and cannot figure it out. I assuming why my app is not launching from the interface is because the fragment doesn't know to communicate with the interface.